# Make functions in map point-free

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have a situation like this:

```
const fun = (x,y) => fun1(fun2(x,y), fun3(x,y), fun4(x,y));
const a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ].map(fun);
```

I see `x`, `y` everywhere. Is there something that can be done to make this point-free?

**Update:**

Real life example for this :

```
data.map((gist, index) =>
  ifElse(
    checkForSingleFile(gist, index),
    toGistFile(gist, index),
    toGistFolder(gist, index)
  )
);
```

I am using Ramda's [`IfElse`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ifElse)

Comment: Possible for you to create a working example of what you are dealing with please?

Comment: the `fun` function take two arguments and with the `map()` you only give one param to the `fun` function and the `const fun = (x,y) => fun1(fun2(x,y), fun3(x,y), fun4(x,y));` is totally incorrect

Comment: point-free is a way to write js functions and to compose them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the arguments to `ifElse` as it returns the apt function which will have the arguments of the either `toGistFile` or `toGistFolder`, both of which are same in your case:

```js
const {
  ifElse
} = R;

const data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const checkForSingleFile = () => {
  return Math.random() > 0.5;
}

const toGistFile = (gist, index) => {
  console.log('file');
  //return function(gist, index) {};
}

const toGistFolder = (gist, index) => {
  console.log('folder');
  //return function(gist, index) {};
}

data.map(
  ifElse(
    checkForSingleFile,
    toGistFile,
    toGistFolder
  )
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@0.25/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I took the liberty to update the answer to make it even more point-free, now there are no parameters anywhere. This is awesome. Now I need to learn why this works, I know it works because Ramda supports currying by default, but need to get the concepts more strong so that I can come up with these kinds of solutions myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok the first snippet show you how to do it with Vanilla JS :

```js
const compose = (points, fns) => {
  let output = points;
  points.map( (p,i) => {
    fns.map( fn => output[i] = fn(output[i]) );
  });
  return output;
}

const funA = ({x,y}) => ({x: x*2, y: y*2});
const funB = ({x,y}) => ({x: x*2, y: y*2});
const sqrt = ({x,y}) => ({x: Math.sqrt(x), y: Math.sqrt(y)});

const points = [{x:1, y:1}, {x:2, y:2}];

const res = compose(points, [funA, funB, sqrt]); // sqrt(funB(funA(points))) = funA ¤ funB ¤ sqrt

console.log(res);
```

And now with a library designed for function composing (ramda.js):

```js
const funA = ({x,y}) => ({x: x*2, y: y*2});
const funB = ({x,y}) => ({x: x*2, y: y*2});
const sqrt = ({x,y}) => ({x: Math.sqrt(x), y: Math.sqrt(y)});

const points = [{x:1, y:1}, {x:2, y:2}];
const curryFun = R.compose(sqrt, funA, funB);
const resCurry = points.map( curryFun );

console.log(resCurry);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha256-43x9r7YRdZpZqTjDT5E0Vfrxn1ajIZLyYWtfAXsargA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

## PRACTICAL EG :

Here I give an eg about 2D functions, we have a linspace of abscicca and we wanna plot the composed fn :

```js
// declare fn

const lin = x => x * 1.2 + 0.9;
const sin = x => Math.sin(x);
const cos = x => Math.cos(x);

// set the linspace

const linspace = [...new Array(50)].map((val,i) => i/10 );

// set the composed fn

const composed = R.compose(lin, sin, cos);
// we can write : composed = R.compose(lin, Math.sin, Math.cos)

// graph

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var data = {
 labels: linspace,
    datasets: [{
        label: "lin",
        function: lin,
        borderColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
        data: [],
        fill: false
    },
    {
        label: "sin",
        function: sin,
        borderColor: "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
        data: [],
        fill: false
    },
    {
        label: "cos",
        function: cos,
        borderColor: "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
        data: [],
        fill: false
    },
    {
        label: "composed",
        function: composed,
        borderColor: "rgba(255, 106, 86, 1)",
        data: [],
        fill: false
    }
    ]
};

Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeInit: function(chart) {
        var data = chart.config.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < data.labels.length; j++) {
             var fct = data.datasets[i].function,
                 x = data.labels[j],
                 y = fct(x);
                data.datasets[i].data.push(y);
            }
        }
    }
});

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha256-43x9r7YRdZpZqTjDT5E0Vfrxn1ajIZLyYWtfAXsargA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-Uv9BNBucvCPipKQ2NS9wYpJmi8DTOEfTA/nH2aoJALw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
   <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```